# Can't store the values in database

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to store the values of the csv file to a database so I have written the fallowing code so that the values could be stored in it but there is no error returned while I am running the code but the values in the database are not getting updated after running it

```
<?php
include('work/connection.php');
$file = fopen("12.csv","r");
while(!feof($file))
{
$name = fgets($file);
$array[] = explode(",",$name);
}
foreach($array as $i){
$query =  $connection->prepare("UPDATE mark SET maths = :maths AND science = 
:science AND social = :social where stuid = :stuid");
$query->bindParam(":maths",$i[2]);
$query->bindParam(":science",$i[3]);
$query->bindParam(":social",$i[4]);
$query->bindParam(":stuid",$i[1]);
$query->execute();
}
?>
```

and the code in connection.php is

```
<?php
try{
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=student;charset=utf8mb4', 
'root', '');
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $err){
echo $err->getMessage();
die();
 }
?>
```

my 12.csv file consists of the fallowing 
ram      6raman32    12    34    45
manoj    6raman33    13    55    23
the above are the two components in my csv file
thankyou
I think the values in my database are stored in the form of varchar but here in the array as string due to which no row getting updtaed as no stuid is matching to that of the array ones I tried converting the elements of it int by using intval but it returns 0 instead of string in int form

Comment: will you show your csv file?

Comment: I cant display the file but the above are the components which are comma seperated in 12.csv file

Comment: change the query to `UPDATE mark SET maths = :maths , science = 
:science , social = :social where stuid = :stuid`

Comment: even tried with comma but it is not getting updated

Comment: actually the csv file is the excel file which is converted to csv and I am using it

Answer (score 0):

Probably your syntax is wrong.
Use comma instead of 'and' in set section.

Comment: I tried even updating only one row maths by removing all the other ones but it has not worked

Comment: Are you sure that your array is not empty?

Comment: And define the $array before your while  loop with a default value of [].

Comment: Also use error_reporting( E_ALL );  may be you will see something interesting then.

Comment: yes the array is not empty i am even printiing it it prints as I have desired it to

Answer (score 0):

the above answer I think is not correct exactly I made thees changes so that the csv file is getting updated into the tables in my database

```
$file = fopen("12.csv","r");
while(!feof($file)){
$data = fgetcsv($file);
$query =  $connection->prepare("UPDATE mark SET maths = :maths , science = 
:science , social = :social where stuid = :stuid");
$query->bindParam(":maths",$data[2]);
$query->bindParam(":stuid",$data[1]);
$query->bindParam(":science",$data[3]);
$query->bindParam(":social",$data[4]);
$query->execute();
}
fclose($file)
```